# toggle extra detail for a record inside an ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a project where the client has supplied a pile of html where I need to plugin the data from our database and have hit a problem that I'm finding difficult to solve....

So first problem is with routing

```
<div ng-repeat="class in vm.classes">
    <div class="class-overview">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="class-title">{{class.description}}</span>
            ... more stuff here 
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="class-information collapse">
         <div class="full-width">
              {{class.longDescription}}
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

he has supplied some javascript to handle the click on class-overview

```
$('.class-overview a').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('.class-overview').on('click',function() {
    $('.class-overview.active').removeClass('active').next('.class-information').collapse('hide');
    $(this).addClass('active').next('.class-information').collapse('show');//.css('top',offset).collapse('show');
});
```

and i have a line like this in my state provider

```
// default route
$urlrouterProvider.otherwise("/")
```

So the problem is that the ui-router handles the click and sends me back to the home page.

The ideal solution is to leave as much of his markup intact, so can anyone tell me how I stop ui-router handling the click?

or failing that, how I might use ng-click and ng-show to get the same effect, i.e. hiding and showing the class-information div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well your question, you want to display the `.class-information` div when you click on the `.class-overview` element.

That can be done by using a variable in a `ng-show` like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="class in vm.classes">
  <div class="class-overview">
    <a href="#" ng-click="display = !display">
      <span class="class-title">{{class.description}}</span>
      ... more stuff here
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="class-information" ng-show="display">
    <div class="full-width">
      {{class.longDescription}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `display` variable will be falsy when you land on the page, therefore the `ng-click` will be executed, this variable will be set to `true`.

I see that you are using a `collapse` class to hide the content if it is collapsed. Then you could use angular [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) to put the `collapse` class when the `display` variable is false. Your `div.class-information` would look like this:

```
<div class="class-information" ng-class="{collapse: !display}">
  <div class="full-width">
    {{class.longDescription}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't work, it toggles the class-information for each class, I only want to toggle the class i clicked on

Comment: Actually i'm talking rubbish, that worked just had to clear my browser cache. I'm kind of embarrassed that it was this easy :-) but I am new to this.  Thanks